# Elm - update elements in a list

Tags: arrays, list, indexing, elm

I just started programming in Elm and am stuck at something:

I would like to have a method that can update fields of elements in a list at a certain index.

My **signature** would look like this:

```
updateElement : List (ID, Task) -> Int -> List (ID, Task)
```

with:

```
type alias Task =
  { description : String, focus : Bool}
```

In this case I would like to set the boolean (focus) of the task at the index given to true and all the others tasks in the list to false.

I already tried with arrays in Elm but then I have to work with Maybe and don't think that is a good solution.

I suppose I will have to work with 'map' to change elements in my list but I don't have any clue how I could change it at a particular index.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `List (Int, Task) -> Int -> List (Int, Task)`? Or `List (ID, Task) -> ID -> List (ID, Task)` where `type alias ID = Int`?

Comment: Also `Task` is probably a bad choice for a name since there is already a [Task](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task) in the core package

Comment: Yes indeed my mistake.. Signature should be 

updateElement : List (ID, Task) -> Int -> List (ID, Task)

where I want to change the nth element of a list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that you've clarified your question, the real answer is a combination of the two updates Chad posted

```elm
updateElement : List (ID, Task) -> Int -> List (ID, Task)
updateElement list indexToFocusOn =
  let
    toggle index (id, task) =
      if index == indexToFocusOn then
        (id, { task | focus = true })
      else
        (id, { task | focus = false })
  in
    List.indexedMap toggle list
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want often to change only the nth element of a list, a `List` would be the wrong data structure. A `List` in elm is implemented as a linked list, which will not fare well in terms of performance with random access.

For that kind of work, you probably should rather use an elm [Array](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Array), and indeed the Array does have a simple function to set the nth element, leaving all the others untouched: [Array.set :: Int -> a -> Array a -> Array a](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Array#set).

On that topic, [this discussion on the elm bug tracker](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-plans/issues/13) could be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to update all elements in the list (to make sure all elements are either False while those matching the ID are True), you can perform a `List.map` over the list, while supplying a function whose job is to check the index and perform the update on the element.

Here's an example with a few minor changes to your example code:

```elm
type alias MyTask =
  { description : String
  , focus : Bool
  }

updateElement : List (a, MyTask) -> a -> List (a, MyTask)
updateElement list id =
  let
    toggle (idx, task) =
      if id == idx then
        (idx, { task | focus = True })
      else
        (idx, { task | focus = False })
  in
    List.map toggle list
```

I changed your signatures to be more generic. Since you provided no indication of what `ID` was, I assumed that the first element in the tuple had to match the type of whatever the second function parameter was. I also replaced `Task` with `MyTask` since there's already a common type in elm called [`Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task).

I'll also mention that there is a [`List.indexedMap`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#indexedMap) function which could let you simplify your function declaration a little bit. If the only reason you have a tuple input and output in your example above is because you need to locate an element by its index, it's probably easier to use `List.indexedMap`. Here's an example:

```elm
updateElement2 : List MyTask -> Int -> List MyTask
updateElement2 list id =
  let
    toggle idx task =
      if id == idx then
        { task | focus = True }
      else
        { task | focus = False }
  in
    List.indexedMap toggle list
```

As you can see, it cuts some of that tuple boilerplate out of the function, making it a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I can use this solution somewhere else :-) But I misexpressed myself for the current problem.. (sorry, my first post..)

Indeed: type alias ID = Int

but I would like to change the nth element of a list with the n given.. 

So signature: updateElement : List (ID, Task) -> Int -> List (ID, Task)

I want to do this because I will sort the list but the focus should stay on the same position in the list.. The ID in the list has other functionality

Sorry for the mixup, hope you can still help me..