# How To Structure A Model So It Can Be Turned Into A Dynamic Form Easily

Tags: elm

I want to have an expert opinion on how to shape a model to make it fit into a table/form.

I tried a lot, but got stuck.

This is my model:

```
type alias Model =
{   freeSyllables : List FreeSyllable
,   addFreeSyllableInput : String
,   addUsageStartInput : Bool
,   addUsageMidInput : Bool
,   addUsageEndInput : Bool
}
```

it's build up out of:

```
type alias FreeSyllable =
{   syllable : String
,   usage : Usage
}

type alias Usage =
{   start : Bool
,   mid : Bool
,   end : Bool
}
```

My view is a mixture between a form and a table. The table/form should be editable per row if I click an edit-Button, which every row should have.

How would you design the model and how would you react upon changes in the table/form?

Thanks ... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inspiration can be taken from [Todo MVC example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/master/Todo.elm)

The idea is having an `editing : Bool` field in `FreeSyllable` record and depending on the value of `editing` either `input` or `text` (or something else) is displayed. The value of `editing` is set by clicking either `edit` or `submit` buttons (or by losing focus event... whatever)

Here is an example just for illustrating how it can work:

The `FreeSyllable` type with a new `editing` field:

```
type alias FreeSyllable =
  {   syllable : String
  ,   usage : Usage
  ,   editing : Bool
  }
```

The `view` that displays either `input` or `text` and sends `UpdateSyllable` and `EditingSyllable` events:

```
view model =
    div []
        [ ul [] (List.indexedMap viewSyllable model.freeSyllables)
        ]

viewSyllable index freeSyllable =
    li []
        [ if freeSyllable.editing then
            div []
                [ input [ onInput (UpdateSyllable index), value freeSyllable.syllable ] []
                , a [ onClick (EditingSyllable index False) ] [ text "submit" ]
                ]
          else
            div []
                [ text freeSyllable.syllable
                , a [ onClick (EditingSyllable index True) ] [ text "edit" ]
                ]
        ]
```

The `update` which updates the model:

```
type Msg
    = UpdateSyllable Int String
    | EditingSyllable Int Bool


update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateSyllable index syllable ->
            let
                updateSyllable idx freeSyllable =
                    if idx == index then
                        { freeSyllable | syllable = syllable }
                    else
                        freeSyllable
            in
                { model | freeSyllables = List.indexedMap updateSyllable model.freeSyllables }

        EditingSyllable index editing ->
            let
                updateSyllable idx freeSyllable =
                    if idx == index then
                        { freeSyllable | editing = editing }
                    else
                        freeSyllable
            in
                { model | freeSyllables = List.indexedMap updateSyllable model.freeSyllables }
```

Hope I've managed to clarify the idea.

Comment: thank you so much, but could you explain the usage of `index` in your code? :D

Comment: That's because of immutability. I can't just update a single syllable, because I need to return a whole `model` with updated syllable from `update` function. That's why an index is passing within an event to identify which syllable to update.

Comment: index is sent automatically ?

Comment: No, there's `indexedMap` function that is used instead of general `map`: `List.indexedMap viewSyllable model.freeSyllables`. `indexedMap` expects `viewSyllable` function to take 2 args (an index and an iterated element).

Comment: oh, thanks. and do you know where I can learn more about using indexes in Elm?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there's some resources exactly on this topic. You can just keep in mind that there is such a solution for this general problem. Though, there's SO question exactly about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502706/elm-update-elements-in-a-list